# Absolutely Continuous measures and Hellinger integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $\mu , \nu$ be two probability measures on $(\Omega , \mathcal{F}).$  Suppose we have a probability measure $\lambda$ such that both $\mu , \nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.  Define $H(\mu,\nu)=\int_\Omega \sqrt{\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}}d\lambda$.  I have two questions my book says I can take this integral is independent of choice of $\lambda$ and that we could take $\lambda=\frac{1}{2}(\mu +\nu)$.  Can someone explain why $H(\mu,\nu)$ is independent of $\lambda$ choice and why the given $\lambda$ fits our criteria.  Sorry if these should be obvious.  I have forgotten most of what I learned about abs. continuity in Real Analysis not that we were taught much as that section was mainly skimmed.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Recall the defintion: $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ if and only if $\lambda(A) = 0$ implies$\mu(A) = 0$ for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$. 

Now, if $0 = \lambda(A) = \tfrac{1}{2}(\mu(A) + \nu(A))$, then, since $\nu(A) \geq 0$, we must have $\mu(A) = 0$. So $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$. The analogous proof shows $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$.

Comment: @JasonJones Good point.  That was really obvious...oops.  Thanks!  Any ideas on the other question?

Comment: $\lambda$ as a measure determines how the summation will be performed not the result. You can think about summation of some discrete numbers. Does it matter which one to sum before and which one later?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\lambda_1 = \frac{1}{2}(\mu + \nu)$. Let $\lambda$ be a measure such that $\mu$ and $\nu$ are absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$. Then $\lambda_1$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$ (verify). So the density $d\lambda_1 / d\lambda$ is defined.

Then
\begin{align*}
H(\mu,\nu) &= \int \sqrt{\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda}\frac{d\nu}{d\lambda}} d\lambda \\
&= \int \sqrt{\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_1}\frac{d\lambda_1}{d\lambda}\frac{d\nu}
{d\lambda_1}\frac{d\lambda_1}{d\lambda} } d\lambda \\
&= \int \sqrt{\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_1}\frac{d\nu}
{d\lambda_1} \left( \frac{d\lambda_1}{d\lambda} \right)^2 } d\lambda \\
&= \int \sqrt{ \frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_1}\frac{d\nu}
{d\lambda_1}}\frac{d\lambda_1}{d\lambda} d\lambda \\
&= \int \sqrt{\frac{d\mu}{d\lambda_1}\frac{d\nu}
{d\lambda_1}} d\lambda_1
\end{align*}
The last integral doesn't depend on $\lambda$.